# Logical operatin in python: Value 1 or Value 2 not in list

Tags: python, list, if-statement, logical-operators

Why does thins not work:

```py
if "update" or "create" not in sys.argv:
    usage()
```

```sh
$ python myScript.py update
# In if

$ python myScript.py create
# In if
```

Goal: How can I check if neither "update" nor "create" is in the list, then the code in the if statement runs?

Comment: Take a look at the `argparse` module, in particular subcommands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your code to:

```
if "update" not in sys.argv and "create" not in sys.argv:
    usage()
```

If you need to check many values from list of possible then use next solution with [all()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_all.asp):

```
if all((s not in sys.argv) for s in ["update", "create"]):
    usage()
```

Or another solution for list of values using [sets](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Sets)-intersection, use next solution only when you need speed or lists are long, otherwise prefer previous solution with `all()` as more readable/understandable:

```
if len(set(["update", "create"]) & set(sys.argv)) == 0:
   usage()
```

Note: `set(list_object)` code constructs set from list each time this code is called, and takes time, hence if this code runs many times construct set in variable like `a = set(list_a)` and reuse `a` later many times.

Comment: I do not understand your solution with set. Why do you use it, why also with sys.argv and hence why is there check if both ==0?

Comment: @WorkoutBuddy In general `set(list_obj)` creates a set out of list of any simple type, like strings or integers. `["update", "create"]` is a list of strings, and `sys.argv` is also simple list of strings. [set](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Sets) is same like sets in mathematics, it contains only one instance of each value inside it, and what is most important has very fast (constant time) of checkin if any value is inside this set or not. Set intersection `&` returns set containing only elements that are inside both sets same time.

Comment: Also `len(set_obj) == 0` checks that set `set_obj` is emtpy, contains no elements. Hence when I do check `if len(set(a) & set(b)) == 0` this will be true if and only if there are no same elements inside `a` and `b` same time. Set intersection just is very efficient way to check two or more lists contain same elements. But the last my solution with `all()` operator is the most pythonic and readable way, use it instead of sets. Use sets only for quite large data (hundreds of elements in list) when you need very fast speed, I just provided it for possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to

```
if "update" or ("create" not in sys.argv):
    usage()
```

as "update" is truthy, it will always evaluate `usage`

What you meant is probably

```
if "update" not in sys.argv and "create" not in sys.argv:
    usage()
```